# OVER partition BY not giving correct result

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

```
select ite_code,specification,x_unit , 
Cast (( Row_number() OVER( partition BY ite_code, specification, x_unit   ORDER BY ite_code, specification, x_unit ) ) AS  NUMERIC(18, 4))  partition_no  from (
select ite_code ='110001010001', specification= 'Sample 1',x_unit= 'NOS' union all 
select ite_code ='110001010001', specification= 'Sample 1',x_unit= 'NOS' union all 
select ite_code ='110001010001', specification= 'Sample 2',x_unit= 'NOS' union all 
select ite_code ='110001010001', specification= 'Sample 2',x_unit= 'NOS'    ) a
```

gives result

```
ite_code    specification   x_unit  partition_no
110001010001    Sample 1    NOS 1.0000
110001010001    Sample 1    NOS 2.0000
110001010001    Sample 2    NOS 1.0000
110001010001    Sample 2    NOS 2.0000
```

but i need result like

```
ite_code    specification   x_unit  partition_no
110001010001    Sample 1    NOS 1.0000
110001010001    Sample 1    NOS 1.0000
110001010001    Sample 2    NOS 2.0000
110001010001    Sample 2    NOS 2.0000
```

whats wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you intend to use a rank function here:

```
SELECT
    ite_code,
    specification,
    x_unit, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ite_code, specification, x_unit) AS partition_no
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    ite_code,
    specification,
    x_unit;
```

The major changes I made to your query were to swap `ROW_NUMBER` for `DENSE_RANK`, and to remove the partition.